# Mule CISF transport failing in Cloud Hub

Tags: mule, cloudhub

I have use case as below.

Created a sample mule flow using smb connector as inbound which reads the files from local network on specific machine and its working fine.

Currently I have a problem that I want deploy this code to cloud hub and want to read the files from same shared location.

Can some one please guide what are the steps need to taken care?

is this achievable using VPC ?

Comment: So you want an application deployed in the cloud to access the file system of one of your on-premise servers?

Comment: yes the file system will be on-premise.Need to connect it via cloud hub.

Comment: ok david, thanks for your response. is there any step by step guidelines to set up VPC ? I have gone through mule documentation but didn't find clear information on VPC.

Comment: Fill the "VPC Discovery Form" ( downloadable from http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Virtual+Private+Cloud ) and send it to the CloudHub team: they'll guide you for the next step.

Comment: thanks david for the response

Answer (score 0):

The original answer was provided by David Dossot in the comments, however the link is outdated.
To summarize, to connect from a CloudHub application to an on-premise or private serivce you need to establish some kind of network connectivity. For that CloudHub requieres a [VPC](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/virtual-private-cloud) and [a connectivity link](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/vpc-connectivity-methods-concept). The process for the later is described at the documentation page [To Request VPC Connectivity to Your Network](https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-manager/to-request-vpc-connectivity).